# discord bot return an async functions value synchronously

Tags: asynchronous, attributes, python-3.6, discord

I've tried not to ask the question so i tried for 2 days to solve this :( i couldn't . here i'm
im just trying to access the list 'Signals' outside the async function to work with it later on my sync code .

this is the async function its from a discord wrapper 'discord.py'
it reads messages on a specific channel. my goal is to get some list out of every message content .

```
import asyncio
from syncer import sync
import discord
import os
import time
from discord.ext import commands

class A:

    TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXX"
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")


    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        autor = message.author
        content = message.content
        channel = message.channel.id
        while ( channel == 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ):
            if #some filters 
                Signal =[message.content]

                return Signal #'till here the code functions and i get the list' 

 bot =A()
 tasks = asyncio.ensure_future(bot.on_message())
 loop =asyncio.get_event_loop()
 loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))

 bot.client.run(bot.TOKEN)
```

this is me trying to get the Signal list :

```
bot =A()
tasks = asyncio.ensure_future(bot.on_message()) 
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
bot.client.run(bot.TOKEN)
```

> loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
>   AssertionError: yield from wasn't used with future

i tried to use an async_to_sync Wrapper called Syncer :

```
bot =A()
b = sync(bot.on_message(message))
assert  Signal ==b()
```

> b = sync(bot.on_message(message))
>   NameError: name 'message' is not defined
>   Unclosed client session
>   client_session:

when i define message :

```
message = {}
bot =A()
b = sync(bot.on_message(message))
assert  Signal ==b()
```

> ```
> b = sync(bot.on_message(message))
> ```
>
> TypeError: on_message() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
>   Unclosed client session
>   client_session:

im sorry again for the dumb question i know im probably doing it all wrong 
im trying my best to learn 
thanks

Comment: That's not really how it works. When you define an `on_message` event, that coroutine will be called later every time the bot sees a message.  You can still call it manually, but you'll have to pass it a `Message` object. What exactly do you want to do with that `Signal` object once you have it?

Comment: im writing a code which will act based on the content of the message whenever a new message is posted on the channel . the Signal basically a list which contains 3 strings , so the rest of the code will do ' if signal [0] == 'something' do something

Comment: You should probably just put that functionality in its own function (or coroutine), then call that from your `on_message`.

Comment: thanks @PatrickHaugh i thought about that , but it seemed like the easy way because the rest of the code is long and this was supposed to be just the trigger to run it if that make sense , i wanted to make it look better